# Custom options cannot be selected in MUI Autocomplete?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to use the MUI `Autocomplete` with a custom `renderOption` property. Doing so I cannot select an option anymore. What is wrong?

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/combobox-material-demo-forked-qy27f)

```
<Autocomplete
  disablePortal
  id="combo-box-demo"
  options={top100Films}
  sx={{ width: 300 }}
  renderOption={(props, option) => (
    <div style={{ padding: "4px 10px" }}>
      {option.label + " " + option.year}
    </div>
  )}
  renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Movie" />}
/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to spread the props provided by MUI `Autocomplete`. Without it, MUI cannot provide `onClick` to know when the option changes or `key` to identify the option, so your option doesn't work:

```
renderOption={(props, option) => (
  <div {...props} style={{ padding: "4px 10px" }}>
    {option.label + " " + option.year}
  </div>
)}
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]